# Performing multiple actions with Python ternary conditional operator

Tags: python, conditional-operator

This simple program reads a list of words from a text file and writes a sublist to another file with a "Total words" count for the sublist:

```
wordList = readFile.read().split(', ')
totalWords = 0

for word in wordList:
    if ('e' in word):
         writeFile.write(word + '\n')
         totalWords += 1

writeFile.write("Total words: " + str(totalWords))
readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Using Python's ternary conditional:

```
for word in wordList:
    writeFile.write(word + '\n') if ('e' in word) else 'false'
```

I would like to know if there is a way to perform the write operation and increment totalWords in a single ternary conditional.
I'm also wondering, rather than using 'false' or None, is there a more appropriate way of handling the else condition since we are merely skipping over a word that doesn't meet the condition?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't really perform the write operation and increment `totalWords` using a single ternary statement(one liner). you are already implementing the code correctly and there is no need to modify your code.**

If you want to enhance the code, you can use the `with` compound statement as follows,

```
with open('read_filename', 'r') as readFile, open('write_filename', 'w') as writeFile:
    wordList = readFile.read().split(', ')
    totalWords = 0

    for word in wordList:
        if ('e' in word):
            writeFile.write(word + '\n')
            totalWords += 1

    writeFile.write("Total words: " + str(totalWords))
```